# Comparar dos numeros en python

Tags: python

He escrito un código que compara dos números A y B y devuelve como respuesta cuantos dígitos del numero B coinciden en su posición con el numero A y cuantos no coinciden en su posición.

Pondré varios ejemplos para mayor claridad. Supongamos que el número A = 1234 y el número B = 1243, entonces el código devuelve la siguiente tupla = (2, 2).

El primer 2 porque B tiene el 1 y 2 en los mismos indices que los tiene A (indices 0 y 1) y el segundo 2 de la tupla dice que los otros 2 dígitos de B si los tiene A pero están en diferente indice.

Pondre otro ejemplo: si A = 1234 y B = 1200 entonces el código deberá devolver (2, 0). En este caso el 0 dice que B contiene 2 digitos que A no contiene.

Pondre un último ejemplo: A = 1234, B = 4321. En este caso el código debería devolver (0, 4), porque ningún digito del numero B ocupa la exacta posición que ocupan en A.

Aquí les dejo mi código

```
def match(a, b):
    correct, so_so = 0, 0
    b_str, a_str = str(b), str(a)
    common = [x for x in a_str if x in b_str]
    matched_nums = []
    if b == a:
        correct += len(b_str)
    else:
        for i in range(len(b_str)):
            if a_str[i] == b_str[i]:
                correct += 1
                matched_nums.append(b_str[i])
        for s in common:
            if a_str.index(s) != b_str.index(s) and s not in matched_nums:
                so_so += 1
    return correct, so_so
```

Tengo dos preguntas:

La primera pregunta: no entiendo porque mi código cuando, por ejemplo, a = 1234 y b = 3333 me devuelve (1, 0) es decir, el 1 te dice que hay un digito en el número B que ocupa la misma posición que en el número A. Y el 0 te dice que ninguno de los 3 restantes dígitos de B están contenidos en A.

Hasta ahora todo bien, pero lo que no entiendo es por que cuando por ejemplo a = 1204 y b = 0000 entonces mi código me devuelve como respuesta (0, 1), no reconociendo que hay un dígito en B que ocupa igual posición en A, que es el 0 en el indice 2.

La segunda pregunta: pido que por favor, si no pueden darme una respuesta la primera pregunta, que me creen un código que devuelva una tupla de dos números,  diciendo el primero cuantos dígitos de B coinciden  en su posición con A y el segundo número diciendo cuantos dígitos de B están contenidos en A pero en diferente posición.

El numero A puede tener duplicados, por ejemplo A = 1223, y B = 1232, entonces la respuesta del código debería ser (2, 2).

Answer (score 0):

### Primera parte

Tu problema viene de que le estás pasando los argumentos como enteros, en vez de como cadenas.

Aunque dentro de la función lo conviertes en cadena con `str()` tienes que tener en cuenta que el entero que hayas recibido **no tendrá ceros por la izquierda**. El número 0000 y el 0 son en el fondo el mismo. Por esa razón cuando le pasas `0000` lo que recibe la función es `0` que al ser convertido en cadena resulta en la cadena `"0"`. En ese caso tu función está dando la respuesta correcta.

Si en cambio pruebas a llamarla así: `match("1204", "0000")` verás que ahora sí retorna lo que esperas, `(1, 0)`.

Por otro lado si hubieras intentado llamarla pasándole por ejemplo `0003` habrías obtenido un error, ya que Python no te permite escribir un entero que comience por cero, salvo el caso particular de `0000` (y la verdad que no conocía esta excepción, habría pensado que tendría que darte el mismo error que `0003`).

### Segunda parte

Respecto a tu segunda pregunta, no está claro lo que pides ¿no es exactamente lo mismo que lo que ya tienes implementado? Salvo que te refieras a la posibilidad de tener dígitos duplicados en A y que sean contados correctamente.

En este caso una implementación podría ser la siguiente (pero la función debe recibir **cadenas** y no enteros, ya que con enteros no es posible pasar ceros por la izquierda):

```
def match(a, b):
    correct, so_so = 0, 0
    # Crear listas con los digitos
    a_l = list(a)
    b_l = list(b)

    # Primera pasada. Contar y eliminar de las listas los que coinciden en su sitio
    for d_a, d_b in zip(a,b):
      if d_a == d_b:
        correct += 1
        a_l.remove(d_a)
        b_l.remove(d_b)

    # Segunda pasada, entre los que quedan en a_l, 
    # contar y eliminar los que están en b_l
    for d_a in a_l:
      if d_a in b_l:
        so_so += 1
        b_l.remove(d_a)
    return correct, so_so
```

Demostración con unos cuantos casos de prueba (observa que en todos estos ejemplos son cadenas lo que se le está pasando a la función, y no enteros):

```
for a, b, esperado in [("1234", "1243", (2,2)), 
                       ("1234", "1200", (2,0)),
                       ("1234", "4321", (0,4)),
                       ("1234", "3333", (1,0)),
                       ("1204", "0000", (1,0)),
                       ("1223", "1232", (2,2)),
                       ("2233", "1322", (0,3)),
                       ("2223", "1322", (1,2))]:
    print(f"a={a}, b={b}, esperado={esperado}, resultado={match(a,b)}")
```

Produce:

```
a=1234, b=1243, esperado=(2, 2), resultado=(2, 2)
a=1234, b=1200, esperado=(2, 0), resultado=(2, 0)
a=1234, b=4321, esperado=(0, 4), resultado=(0, 4)
a=1234, b=3333, esperado=(1, 0), resultado=(1, 0)
a=1204, b=0000, esperado=(1, 0), resultado=(1, 0)
a=1223, b=1232, esperado=(2, 2), resultado=(2, 2)
a=2233, b=1322, esperado=(0, 3), resultado=(0, 3)
a=2223, b=1322, esperado=(1, 2), resultado=(1, 2)
```

Comment: Si, un codigo que haga lo mismo que el mio, pero que cuando introduzcas como B el numero 0000 te devuelva el tuple (1, 0) en vez de (0, 1)

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta. Pero no se si usted puede construir ese codigo

Comment: En la respuesta te explico que no es posible pasarle a una función 0000 como entero, ya que la función recibirá 0. Lo que tienes que hacer es pasarle a la función cadenas en vez de enteros. Cuando le pasas en B la cadena `"0000"` sí te funciona como esperas (aunque no está implementado el caso en que pueda haber duplicados en A, que no sé si es eso lo que preguntabas también)